# Generate 6 digit unique number per day basis

Tags: java

I Need to generate 6 digit  random number per day basis using java

- It may repeat but not in next 1 hour if all 6 digit number not available .
- I am not using Database.
- Not storing any sequence/state of object.

  Currently i am using blow code.

  ```
   //Locale is JAVA Locale Value like "IN","ZN","EN" etc. 
  public String generateTaceNumber(String locale) {
   StringBuilder traceNumber = new  StringBuilder(generateLocalTime(locale));
        String traceNumberGenerated = traceNumber.toString();
  List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
  for(char c:traceNumberGenerated.toCharArray()){
      characters.add(c);
  }
  StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(traceNumberGenerated.length());
  while(characters.size()!=0){
      //generate random number
      int randPicker = (int)(Math.random()*characters.size());
      output.append(characters.remove(randPicker));
  }
  //System.out.println("finaloutput :"+output);
      return output.toString();
  }

  //it return lcoal time in string format.
  public String generateLocalTime(String locale) {
  Date yourDate = new Date();
  Locale yourLocale = new Locale("en", LOCALE);
  DateFormat tf = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, yourLocale);
  String formattedTime = tf.format(yourDate);
  //System.out.println("formattedTime "+formattedTime);
  String time = formattedTime.substring(0, formattedTime.indexOf(' '));
  String[] parts = time.split(":");
  String formatedTimeVal = "";
  for(int i=0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      String subVal = parts[i];
      if(subVal.length()==1) {
          subVal = "0" + subVal;
      }
      formatedTimeVal = formatedTimeVal + subVal;
  }
  //System.out.println("formatted Time val :" +formatedTimeVal);
  return formatedTimeVal;
  ```

  }

  Output:

  formattedTime 8:09:54 PM IST

  formatted Time val :080954

  finaloutput :405809

Above Code give 6 digit number but problem is if i request within a second it give me same number.

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: Blow code seems an apropos typo.

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
class randm{

long i = 0;
for(int j=0 ; j<10; j++)
{
i = (Math.random()*100000+100000);
System.out.println(i+" ");
}

}
```

Comment: If you have a solution to the problem and you want to contribute, you have to take care of how you write down your answer, in order to be useful to the other users. Explain your solution, and indent your code decently! Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).